# Python tags and versions

Tags: discussion, tags

It would seem a [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) is in order, should it be a separate tag or alias for [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting)?

Also, should [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) or [python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) have different versions, or that would be irrelevant?

Comment: With regards to versioning, the important differences between Python 2 and 3 would be rare enough that we shouldn't need distinct tags. Just specify which one in the question if necessary.

Comment: You can also script in C and C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is the only scripting language used in Blender, any questions related to it can stay under [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) as they might extend past the api and into the language a bit, say something like *'stringifying'* an object `str(obj)` for use in the gui, no need to start derivations. Let's try and keep everything as clean as possible.

*As mentioned below* [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) *already exists, but keep in mind that Python based questions could be allowed to a degree as it relates to general Blender excluding scripting.*

*Examples..*

- Do I need to download and install Python before using Blender?
- What version of Python does Blender use and how can I tell?

Comment: At the moment, [tag:scripting] exists and [tag:python] doesn't... Besides, the version question still holds

Comment: @JNF python usage questions can be asked that don't directly relate to scripting but do relate to Blender.

Comment: So you're saying two separate tags are in order?

Comment: @JNF quite possibly, I have edited it into the answer.

Comment: Thank you. That wasn't clear from the previous version of your answer.

Answer (score 3):

I think it would make sense to have separate tags at least for `python-2.x` and `python-3.x` to keep compatibility straight. These two versions of Python are not perfectly compatible, and if either the OP or the answerer ever wants to include a code snippet, it could be useful to have these tags.