# Should 'scripting' and 'Python' be made tag synonyms?

Tags: discussion, tags, tag-synonyms

I've noticed that nearly every question about scripting ends up getting tagged with both of these tags. Do we really need them both?

As I see it, scripting in Blender can only be done in Python, and the only time while using Blender you would encounter raw Python would be while scripting. Is there anything one adds that the other doesn't?

Comment: There's also a python-api tag.

Answer (score 11):

## No

There are currently questions here that use [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) but aren't directly related to [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) and there are sure to be more in the future.

Example: [How to make Blender use Python2.x?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-to-change-the-python-version-that-blender-uses)

Also see my [answer to a similar question](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/38/12)

Comment: why not using a "python-scripting" tag instead of "scripting" to exclude C/C++ and easy tag choice (auto-complete)

Comment: We're looking to change this soon @Bithur. This is showing its age.

Answer (score 5):

No.

As blender expands, they may also be referring to OSL. They also may be referring just to Python(as stated in iKlsR's answer).

Comment: OSL does not belong under either tag and should have one of it's own.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm saying that an OSL *script* may be tagged.

Answer (score -1):

To share my 2 cents . . .

They might also be C/C++ scripting/plugin development.

Comment: Anything C/C++ is off-topic and "C/C++ scripting?" :)

Comment: @iKlsR off-topic? [C/C++ scripting](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Doc/Tools/Tips_for_Coding_Blender)

Comment: From a developer or even average user viewpoint this is actually not directly related to Blender. See #5 here http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic *(I did not make this list by myself, it was from bits and pieces contributed here and there)*