# When to use 'scripting', when to use 'python' tags?

Tags: discussion, tags

In case I have a question about *How can I use python to ....*, should I use the tags 'scripting' or 'python'? What are most important differences?

Answer (score 6):

See [Should 'scripting' and 'Python' be made tag synonyms?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/599)

In addition, here is my interpretation of the differences:

- [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) is for questions involving automation of tasks via scripts.

  These could be shell scripts calling blender with various options, or python scripts running within blender.
  I've also seen this tag used for [osl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/osl) when the question is more about the language itself, rather than accomplishing a specific something in it.
  And since we don't have a [glsl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/glsl) tag at the moment, [opengl](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/opengl) + [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) seems to be used when glsl code is involved.
- [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) is for questions pertaining to the python api.

These will often overlap, in which case both can be used.

Comment: Great answer, clarifies it quite well