# Suggestion: Merge `python` and `python-api` tags

Tags: discussion, tags

I would recommend that the [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) and [python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) tags be merged.

**Rationale:**

- **⇒** The only part of Python that should be discussed on Blender.SE is the Blender Python (bpy) API. Anything else is not in the scope of Blender.SE and should be asked on [StackOverflow](http://www.stackoverflow.com/).
- **⇐** Clearly anything related to the Python API is related to Python.

I have already submitted a synonym request at [the `python-api` tag](https://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/python-api/synonyms) but I don't have enough rep to suggest it on the `python` tag. If possible it should probably be that [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) is kept while [python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) is removed, because the latter is unnecessarily verbose.

Comment: Related [Should 'scripting' and 'Python' be made tag synonyms?](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/97/should-scripting-and-python-be-made-tag-synonyms).

Comment: I'm starting to think this should be so after all. [Will discuss it a bit](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/8888/the-renderfarm?tab=schedule) and make a decision. A small subset of python will still be allowed but we don't need both tags, I think [python-api] should go.

Answer (score 1):

### Update

The [python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) tag was removed since people ignore the subtle differences, it's now just [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python).

---

I am tempted to merge these ever so often but since we support a strict subset of Python related questions, it is ok to have both of these in my opinion.

There are currently questions here that use [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) but aren't directly related to [python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api). I agree that tagging every [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) and [python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) related question with [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) is kinda redundant and the last two seem to be used interchangeably but at the moment, the tag is general enough to also apply to these.

Here are some tagged Python questions that have little or nothing to do with the api.

- [Interactive Python workflow for Blender beginner](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2964/interactive-python-workflow-for-blender-beginner)
- [How to make Blender use Python2.x?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-to-change-the-python-version-that-blender-uses)
- [How to interface with blender using IPython from terminal?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2918/use-the-terminal-i-called-blender-from-as-my-console)
- [Environment for implementing/testing Computer Graphics algorithms](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2517/environment-for-implementing-testing-computer-graphics-algorithms)
- [Can I run a Python script step by step in Blender?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2502/can-i-run-a-python-script-step-by-step-in-blender)
- [Is there a way to acces external .blend file's data with python script?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/2410/is-there-a-way-to-acces-external-blend-files-data-with-python-script)
- [How to make Blender use Python2.x?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/302/how-to-change-the-python-version-that-blender-uses)
- [Console vs scripting python constants](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1896/console-vs-scripting-python-constants)
- [Using blender as a python module](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1574/using-blender-as-a-python-module)
- [Which modules are guaranteed to be present in Blender's Python?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1116/which-modules-are-guaranteed-to-be-present-in-blenders-python)

What we could do however is revisit the scope of this tag.

Related:

- [Should 'scripting' and 'Python' be made tag synonyms?](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/97/12)
- [Python tags and versions](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/37/12)