# Why is there still a python-api tag suggestion?

Tags: bug, tags

[python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) was merged into [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) a while ago. Why does it still appear in the prompt as a separate tag?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) appears because it is a tag synonym for [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python), if you chose either, it would give you the same tag. Originally, there was [python-api](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python-api) and the less used [scripting](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/scripting) then there was a trial period when we were [deciding](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/280/12) whether or not to just make one giant python tag or keep separate variants.

However, since the [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) is shorter and the one being used, the other is no longer needed and has now been removed. [python](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/python) is now the sole tag.

Comment: I thought synonyms were only displayed underneath the suggestion for the parent tag (where it says "also:"). E.g. if you type in `scr` in the tag input field, you will get a suggestion for [tag:scripting] with a little "also:" for [tag:script], but no separate suggestion for [tag:script]. Am I missing something? Or . . .?

Comment: @gandalf3 That is one aspect, try it. For eg [`modeling`](http://blender.stackexchange.com/tags/modeling/synonyms) has 2 synonyms, `model` and `modelling`, enter either on a question and it will change to `modeling` when you save.

Comment: I noticed that with `python-api`. However, both of those tags (`model` and `modelling`) don't seem to have their own separate prompt (like `python-api` does). Why does `python-api` seem to be the only synonym to have a prompt?

Comment: @gandalf3 This is because the `python-api` tag was still around. It has been removed now so it shouldn't appear.